# Запускаю код для телеграм бота. выдает ошибку. TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, telebot

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('1788376320:xCxcEpIFmhT9O7w')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Howdy, how are you doing?")


bot.polling()
```

Результат:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Константин/untitled1/telegram bot.py", line 7, in <module>
    def send_welcome(message):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

если задать вот такой параметр:

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN", parse_mode=None)
```

то выдает такую ошибку:

```
      File "C:/Users/Константин/untitled1/telegram bot.py", line 3, in <module>
    bot = telebot.TeleBot('1788376320:9xCxcEpIFmhT9O7w', parse_mode=None)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'parse_mode'
```

код изначально брал из документации https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI

Answer (score 0):

Убедитесь, что у вас установлена только библиотека pyTelegramBotAPI, а не telebot

Проверить это можно с помощью команды `pip freeze`

Если у вас также установлена библиотека telebot, то следует удалить ее `pip uninstall telebot`

Comment: на pip freeze получил список. там только pyTelegramBotAPI запущен